# Excel Sheet Reading - ClosedXML - Date shown as Number

Tags: c#, closedxml

I have an excel sheet which i am trying to parse. All works correctly except when i have a date e.g. `01-Nov-2016`. 
When trying to read this value via `_value = cell.Value.ToString();`  it is returning just a number.

After the sheet has been parsed the value `4426979` is displayed.

When I debug the codebase the `cell.Value` equals `[$-4426979]d-mmm-yy`.

has anyone encountered this issue? 
if so, How do you fix it?

the full Function is:

```
protected string GetCellContents(IXLCell cell)
{
    string _value = string.Empty;
    if (cell.HasFormula)
    {
        _value = cell.ValueCached.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        _value = cell.Value.ToString();
    }

    return _value;
}
```

Comment: Which number is set to `_value`? `ToString()` could format it.

Comment: How about `_value = DateTime.FromOADate(cell.Value.ToString()).ToString();`?

Comment: @C4u I have updated my question

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
string strValue = cell.ValueCached.ToString();
double doubleValue = double.Parse(strValue); // or use double.TryParse if you need
DateTime dateTimeValue = DateTime.FromOADate(doubleValue);
_value = dateTimeValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace .ToString() with .ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")?